# React JS + Wordpress blog

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, reactjs, express

I have a web app built with react js using express webserver. It's running fine now on www.mydomain.com. Now I wanted to add a wordpress blog to www.mydomain.com/blog. I wonder if this is doable? I have done tons of google search but could not find a good answer to this.

I can do this easily using blog.mydomain.com but after some research, the benefits of using www.mydomain.com/blog is much better in terms of seo optimization and traffic etc.

Comment: have you had a look at nginx or haproxy?

Comment: You could use the WP REST API to load WordPress blog posts into your React build, which'd be the nicest and cleanest way of doing things given your current setup, although admittedly the most amount of work.